# write a formula in excel to calculate shift coverage on weekly basis attendance sheet. How to use IF with countif

Tags: countif

[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwIKY.png)

need help in writing a formula to calculate shift coverage on weekly basis attendance sheet. I have tried using countif with if , i am not getting desired result. Have attached the image.

I have tried combining If with Count if , so that it counts first the attendance for that day and then fulfil the condition if covered or not covered. I am just having trouble combining IF and countif or is there any other way around to calculate this.